# Publication in wrong category

Tags: errors

how do I create an error message if the user is trying to publish in a specific category?
I would like to prevent publication in the default category.

Comment: Depending on what you're after, might it not be simpler to just delete the 'uncategorized' category by setting one of your custom categories as the primary? This would mean that no-one could publish to the default 'uncategorized' term, and only choose your set options.

Comment: The default category cannot be deleted. You can decide to change it. But when a draft is created, it is always saved in the default category. I need this to be prevented.